# How to filter specific word from .TXT file

Tags: vb.net, text, filter

I am using Visual Basic.

I have a .txt file which contains random words with many sentences. I want to import that file content into my Rich text box in my VB form, and filter specific words from it, then copying those words into another Rich text box in the same form.

Any suggestions how I can do it?

Comment: Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour] then hover over the VB and VBscript tags, read them and decide which one really applies

Comment: See `replace` function.